# How to send Large datatable to WCF using basic http binding

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I am not able to send large datatable to WCF. 
My Web config file of application is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-AutoStart" value="true" />
    <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-Sleep" value="60000" />
    <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-Age" value="120000" />
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="TimeAttendanceDBConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=MICROSYS-PC3\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TimeAttendanceDB;User ID=sa;pwd=micro;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Speech, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
        <add assembly="log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" allowCookies="true"
                   maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                   maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                   maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="128"
               maxArrayLength="2147483647"
               maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:51746/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
        name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

and my wcf webconfig is given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" 
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
                 closeTimeout="01:50:00" 
                 openTimeout="01:50:00" 
                 sendTimeout="01:50:00" 
                 receiveTimeout="01:50:00" >
          <readerQuotas 
            maxDepth="128" 
            maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <client />
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>

          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>

          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/> 
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ConnectionString" value="Data Source=Microsys_PC3\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TimeAttendanceDB;User ID=sa;pwd=micro;"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I am able to send emply datatable but when it is containing more data it is getting error
please help

Comment: What is the error message? You may need to set includeExceptionDetailInFaults = "true" to get this.

Answer (score 0):

Please Use basicHttpBinding as given below.. It is working fine

`<binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" 
                    closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" 
                    receiveTimeout="00:10:00" 
                    sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    allowCookies="false" 
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" 
                    hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="1000000000" 
                    maxBufferPoolSize="1000000000" 
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000000"
                    messageEncoding="Text" 
                    textEncoding="utf-8" 
                    transferMode="Buffered"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" 
                    maxStringContentLength="1000000000" 
                    maxArrayLength="1000000000"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" 
                    maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
</binding>`

Comment: The posted configs have values of 2,147,483,647 - setting the value to 1,000,000,000 (less than half the original value) will solve the problem how?

Comment: Once I faced these kind of problem,I used the above binding code. 1,000,000,000,  2,147,483,647 Both are working.Second one is Best to use. Thanks @Tim

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason (it's hard to know for sure without knowing what the error message is and how you are consuming the service) is that the binding you've defined (`BasicHttpBinding_IService1`) is not being used by your service, because it is not assigned to an endpoint.  You are getting the default `basicHttpBinding` endpoint with the default values for `basicHttpBinding`.

To resolve this, you can either make your binding definition the default by omitting the `name` attirbute, like this:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
             closeTimeout="01:50:00" 
             openTimeout="01:50:00" 
             sendTimeout="01:50:00" 
             receiveTimeout="01:50:00" >
      <readerQuotas 
        maxDepth="128" 
        maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```

Or defining an endpoint that references that specific binding configuration via the `bindingConfiguration` attribute on the `endpoint` element, like this:

```
<services>
  <service name="yourservicename">
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:51746/Service1.svc" 
                binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"
                contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Both of these changes (pick one) would be in the **service** config file.